# How could I add bookmarks to Internet Explorer with a batch script?

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

As the title says - is there a batch script (preferably with an example) that I could use to add bookmarks to Internet Explorer specifically?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to create new bookmarks? Or are you copying from another location?

Comment: I have a huge list of internal (intranet) links that I would like to set up for colleagues with new laptops.

Answer (score 2):

Using a command file

```
echo [InternetShortcut] > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Google.URL"
echo URL=http://www.google.com >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Google.URL"
echo IconFile=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Google.URL"
echo IconIndex=0 >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Google.URL"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBScript for creating .URL files. This one will put the shortcut on the desktop but you can put them somewhere else if you like.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktopFolder = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
set link = WshShell.CreateShortcut(desktopFolder & "\Stack Overflow.url")
link.TargetPath = "http://stackoverflow.com"
link.Save
```

.stompp

Comment: Special folders are : AllUsersDesktop, AllUsersStartMenu, AllUsersPrograms, AllUsersStartup, Desktop, Favorites, MyDocuments, Programs, Recent, SendTo, StartMenu, Startup

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer favorites are just text files with the .url extension formated like an .ini file that live in the user's Favorites folder.

You can't get the Favorites folder with the cmd processor (i.e. you can't get a direct path to the Favorites folder using a traditional batch file), the best you can do is assume that something like `cd /d %USERPROFILE%\Favorites` will work.

Using the WScript stuff is probably a better solution.